# Updating TextFields upon selecting option choosing/closing UIPickerView without button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am working in Xcode 7 using Swift 2.

I have my UIPickerViews setup in textfields and they are all working as they should.  I close the pickerviews using:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    pickerOptions.resignFirstResponder()
    (etc.)
}
```

My issue is that I have one pickerview that I want to be a "presets" menu that will update 3 regular textfield inputs with a set of values by selecting a pickerview value without the need to update the values with a button.  I'm not entirely sure how to go about this, as I am not very familiar with delegates yet (if it even involves them).  I'm really at a lost on how to update/refresh the ViewController.

I would guess that it has something to do with `textFieldDidEndEditing`  (since I have these classes already setup from setting up the UIPickerView: `UIPickerViewDataSource`, `UIPickerViewDelegate`, `UITextFieldDelegate`) Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

It's all about delegates. I understand you have a pickerView that should set the content of some textFields upon user selection. The pickerView is a stock object that needs to tell your class what's going on without knowing anything specific about your class. It does this by saying, if you implement this protocol that I define, then I will call your functions to let you know. In the case of pickerView, the related protocol is `UIPickerViewDelegate`, and it exposes a property called `delegate` that can only be set to an object that implements the protocol. If the pickerView's delegate is set, it will call that object's `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` function when the user scrolls the pickerView.

You just need to create an object that will conform to the `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol, and set the pickerView's `delegate` property accordingly. More often than not you will just add this ability to your viewController, along the lines of:

```
class viewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        // Now you can update the textField(s)
    }
}
```

Note that the definition of `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` is marked as optional. This means if you say you implement `UIPickerViewDelegate`, but don't define it, the compiler will not let you know. This can be confusing if you accidentally misspell it or get the signature wrong - you will think it's defined but it will never get called.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the delegate method:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row   inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //put your code here
}
```

that belongs to the `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocol.

To see documentation of a protocol on XCode `option` + click on the name of the protocol.